# Why do node_modules keep disappearing from docker after build?

Tags: javascript, node.js, continuous-integration, docker, circleci

I'm mimicking the setup found here https://github.com/mjhea0/node-docker-workflow. Using docker-compose to link 2 docker containers (node, redis).

**Here's the circle ci file:**

```
machine:
  services:
    - docker

dependencies:
  override:
    - sudo pip install -U docker-compose

test:
  override:
    - docker-compose run -d --no-deps node
    - cd node; npm test
```

**And here is my node Dockerfile:**

```
FROM dockerfile/nodejs

RUN mkdir /src

RUN npm install nodemon -g

WORKDIR /src
ADD . /src
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD npm start
```

The tests are constantly failing because `chai` can't be found. This is due to `node_modules` disappearing once the build is complete.

Literally between these 2 steps in the circle.yml file node_modules are installed by npm install, and then they're gone by the time the npm test command is run.

```
test:
  override:
    - docker-compose run -d --no-deps node
    - cd node; npm test
```

I can't figure out why this is happening. As i'm just starting out with Docker, can someone please (in laymens terms) explain fairly thoroughly what is wrong with the repo i'm using above, and how to solve it.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the dockerfile work without all this extra stuff/crap?   If you are just starting out with docker, perhaps focus on the 'docker' part itself.   If you have VOLUMEs defined, they do not persist.

Comment: Even without the defined volume, it the node_modules don't seem to persist long enough.  `docker-compose run -d --no-deps node` builds and installs the node_modules via npm install, and then by the time this is run `cd node; npm test`, they're gone. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out it was something very, very simple, and probably rather silly/obvious.

The tests aren't being run ***inside*** the container.

`docker-compose run -d --no-deps node`

This line runs the container in ***detached*** mode. Which means when the next command runs, it's running *outside* the container.

To solve this, simply remove the `-d`, so the next command runs inside the container.

`docker-compose run --no-deps node`

Simple.